# Is it legal for a US minor to take puberty blockers /for a doctor to prescribe puberty blockers to a minor without their parents knowledge or consent?

Tags: united-states, medical, parental-rights, transgender

Is it legal to prescribe a minor puberty blockers without their parents' knowledge or consent? Is there an age limit?

Semi-related example:
In Germany, it is legal to prescribe girls birth control pills without their parents' knowledge at the age of 14. Is this case in the US or the UK for hormone blockers?

The Times claims that at least in the UK, you can get hormone blockers even if your parents are against it.

[Parents’ consent not needed to block puberty, say judges](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/tavistock-nhs-trust-wins-appeal-over-puberty-blockers-for-children-7k9pg9gfw)

This is a purely legal question out of curiosity.

Comment: The article in question is blocked behind a pay wall.  It cannot be read unless you subscribe.

As for your question, the hormone blockers in question are more than likely to delay puberty and have nothing to do with Birth Controll (typically, puberty blockers are used as part for transgender therapy).

Comment: I know. My spelling might be poor as I am a non native speaker. I would like to know if a minor can get this medicine without its parent knowledge and / or its parent consent. This is the case tor the birth control pill, which is why I used it as an example.

Comment: Within the U.S., it's likely going to be different depending on the state.  Laws regarding meds and parental consent are typically handled at the state level.

Comment: Even true things printed in The Times become false.

Comment: The Times article is about a Court of Appeal judgment https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/2021/1363.html overturning the judgment of a lower court. It boils down to the lower court inappropriately reached "general age-related conclusions" and gave improper guidance. What matters is the *Gillick* competence of the child - "sufficient understanding and intelligence to understand fully what is proposed" - not solely the fact they are a certain age. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillick_competence

Comment: The title makes it sound like you're asking whether it is legal for the minor to *take* the medication (i.e. literally swallow the pills), but the body of the question seems to be asking instead whether it is legal for the doctor to prescribe them, or for the pharmacy to supply them.  Can you please edit as needed to clarify?

Comment: done. i am looking forward for an answer. it is just curiosity, since i live in Germany and just want to know how things are handled in the US.

Comment: "[Puberty blockers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puberty_blocker)" describes a wide range of drugs prescribed for a variety of purposes in both children and adults, including treating early-onset puberty, treating various hormonal disorders, for cancer of the reproductive system, as well as on trans or non-gender-conforming people. The standard is likely to be different in different cases, e.g. if not prescribing risks serious illness.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, the answer is complicated. First, puberty blockers are approved by the FDA, but only as a treatment for precocious puberty. There is an off-label use for transgender people, which has been outlawed in some states (thus parental consent / notification is irrelevant). That leaves us with general parental consent laws. [This document](https://ndaa.org/wp-content/uploads/Minor-Consent-to-Medical-Treatment-2.pdf) summarizes the laws of various states regarding parental consent, where again it depends on the specific state whether parental notification or consent is required (and at what age). As you can see, the laws are very complex, involving different ages for different treatments. [In Washington](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=71.34.530), the age of consent for outpatient medical treatment is 13. [In Nevada](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/nrs-129.html), parental consent is required until age 18 except for emancipated minors and for limited medical purposes (emergencies, substance abuse and STD treatment...).